# Hiding features on the layer based on other layer's data

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using mapbox-gl and have point and line layers on the map. All layers are vector tiles. Some points lie on the lines, some not and I want to hide points that don't lie on the lines

Is it possible to do it only on the frontend side with writing something like a filter that checks if a point on any line or not? I really don't want to change the backend

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use turf.js in conjunction with mapbox-gl-js?
E.g. you could calculate the distance to the line with http://turfjs.org/docs/#pointToLineDistance for each point, then filter out any points with a distance bigger than 0.